# Category collection retrieves wrong attribute values

Tags: magento-1.9, category

```
    $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('level', 2) level
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', 1)
        ->addFieldToFilter('path', array('like'=> "1/$rootid/%"))
    ;

    foreach ($categories as $category) { yaddayadda() }
```

Calling this from a simple script in the shell directory leads to the correct result. I only get the categories that are active and included in the menu. But when it is called in the normal Magento Block for building the top navigation it somehow changes the attributes of the categories. It shows everyone and when I check the attributes via debugger or var_dump it says "included_in_menu" (or "is_active") is 1. But it's not! It's correctly set in the backend and getting this collection via shell it says the values are 0. I cleared the caches endless times and saved the categories multiple times.

What can possibly cause this?

Comment: Did you try to flush the cache and reindex ?

Comment: Countless times.

Comment: Are you sure the category is associated to the store you're testing ?

Comment: Yes. I checked the store id and the category id. Everything is identical in the shell script and the block code.

Edit: Ok, no it isn't...the store view differs. It's working now...stupid....thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks to Raphael at Digital Pianism I checked the category in the backend again and realized the value was set in another store view. The shell script accessed another one than the magento block.

Comment: No worries, been here, done that ;)